# SQL : create intermediate data from date range

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, range

I have a table as shown here:

| USER | ROI | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2021-11-24 |
| 1 | 4 | 2021-11-26 |
| 1 | 6 | 2021-11-29 |

I want to get the ROI for the dates in between the other dates, expected result will be as below

From 2021-11-24 to 2021-11-30

| USER | ROI | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2021-11-24 |
| 1 | 5 | 2021-11-25 |
| 1 | 4 | 2021-11-26 |
| 1 | 4 | 2021-11-27 |
| 1 | 4 | 2021-11-28 |
| 1 | 6 | 2021-11-29 |
| 1 | 6 | 2021-11-30 |

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use

Answer (score -1):

You may use a calendar table approach here.  Create a table containing all dates and then join with it.  Sans an actual table, you may use an inline CTE:

```sql
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT '2021-11-24' AS dt UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-11-25' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-11-26' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-11-27' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-11-28' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-11-29' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-11-30'
),
cte AS (
    SELECT USER, ROI, DATE, LEAD(DATE) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) AS NEXT_DATE
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT t.USER, t.ROI, d.dt
FROM dates d
INNER JOIN cte t
    ON d.dt >= t.DATE AND (d.dt < t.NEXT_DATE OR t.NEXT_DATE IS NULL)
ORDER BY d.dt;
```